# Sort a list based on member field’s value’s position in another list

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a Person with fields score(int), name(String) and country(String)

```
1, Jane , Spain
2, James, Italy
1, John , Italy
2, Peter , England
3, Thomas , England
3, Martin , England
```

Now I provide another List of Strings which represent country names say : `[Italy, Spain, Norway, England, Germany]`

My requirement is to sort the Person list based on scores first, if they have the same score **then sort by the country names provides in the country names list**. If country names also match then sort by person name.

So finally the person objects should be returned in this order:

```
1, John, Italy
1, Jane, Spain
2, James, Italy
2, Peter, England
3, Martin, England
3, Thomas, England
```

Here is the code I am trying:

```
public static List<Person> sortRecords(List<Person> people, List<String> countries) {
    people.sort((p1, p2) -> {
        int compare = p1.getScore() - p2.getScore();
        if(compare == 0) {
            compare = // how to compare by country names based on provided List<String> countries
            if(compare == 0) {
                compare = p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
            }
        }
        return compare;
    });
}
```

I am stuck at comparing by country names.

Comment: Any reason for negative votes?

Comment: So, each `Person` has a single country and you have a separate country list (which I assume is the "preferred" order, rather than been in alphabetical order)?  Get the index of each country from the list and compare them

Comment: Not a downvoter, but a [mcve] would go along way to helping us understand the issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yes correct I have to compare based on the order given in countries list. So I am stuck at how do I compare based on the countries list now.

Comment: `countries.indexOf(p1.getCountry) - countries.indexOf(p2.getCountry)`

Comment: Perhaps down-votes were because the title and body are not entirely clear. At a glance, your question looked a duplicate of the very common "how to sort my list" question posted by authors too lazy to search Stack Overflow. I edited the title in an effort to be more clear and specific.

Comment: Should "2, Peter, England" comes before "2, James, Italy" since you sort by score, country and then name?  "England" comes before "Italy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`List.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))

```
public static List<Person> sortRecords(List<Person> people, List<String> countries) {
    people.sort((p1, p2) -> {
        int compare = p1.getScore() - p2.getScore();
        if(compare == 0) {
            compare = countries.indexOf(p1.getCountry()) - countries.indexOf(p2.getCountry());
            if(compare == 0) {
                compare = p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
            }
        }
        return compare;
    });
    return people;
}
```

---

Note that as the sort is done inplace, you don't need to return the list, then using  `java.util.Comparator` you can do some nice thing

```
public static void sortRecords(List<Person> people, List<String> countries) {
    people.sort(
         Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getScore)
                   .thenComparingInt(person -> countries.indexOf(person.getCountry()))
                   .thenComparing(Person::getName)
    );
}
```

Comment: Gonna be expensive. Better to create an inverse index lookup with a `Map`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Agreed, but for the current issue, it will suffice

Comment: Just beware, this assumes that the person country exists in the country list, otherwise they could end up at the top of the list ;)

Comment: Nitpicking :) `indexOf` returns `int` so we can use `thenComparingInt` to handle it directly, instead of `getComparing` which would expect `Comparable` which would force `int` to be boxed to `Integer`. Also while `p1.getScore() - p2.getScore();` may be OK for positive values it is generally safer way to use `Integer.compare(p1.getScore(), p2.getScore());` which guarantees to handle comparison correctly without risk of overflowing. Similarly for `indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a stable sorting algorithm to sort the list by name, then by country, and then by score.  See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stability-in-sorting-algorithms/

```
import java.util.*;
class Record {
    int score; String name; String country;
    Record(int s, String n, String c){ score=s; name=n; country=c; }
    public String toString(){ 
      return String.format("[%d, %s, %s]", score, name, country);
    }
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Record[] records = {
              new Record(1, "Jane" ,   "Spain"),
              new Record(2, "James",   "Italy"),
              new Record(1, "John" ,   "Italy"),
              new Record(2, "Peter",   "England"),
              new Record(3, "Thomas",  "England"),
              new Record(3, "Martin", "England")
        };
        Comparator<Record> byScore   = (r1,r2)->r1.score-r2.score;
        Comparator<Record> byCountry = (r1,r2)->r1.country.compareTo(r2.country);
        Comparator<Record> byName    = (r1,r2)->r1.name.compareTo(r2.name);

        System.out.println("===before====");
        Arrays.stream(records).forEach(System.out::println);
        
        Arrays.sort(records, byName); 
        Arrays.sort(records, byCountry);     
        Arrays.sort(records, byScore);
        
        System.out.println("===after====");
        Arrays.stream(records).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output

```
===before====
[1, Jane, Spain]
[2, James, Italy]
[1, John, Italy]
[2, Peter, England]
[3, Thomas, England]
[3, Martin, England]
===after====
[1, John, Italy]
[1, Jane, Spain]
[2, Peter, England]
[2, James, Italy]
[3, Martin, England]
[3, Thomas, England]
```

Comment: As peter and james has same score, my next step is to sort based on country names provided in input list `[Italy, Spain, Norway, England, Germany]` so in this case `Italy comes first then England`.

Comment: I misunderstood the requirement.  :)